# Multi module Spring Boot project with different context paths

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As the title says, I'm trying to create a multi module Spring Boot project that has different context paths for each module.

Let's say I have a bunch of core functionality in one module, and let's call it 'core'. This includes defining entities, DAOs and common functionality. I'd like to add two more modules, (for instance 'frontend' and 'admin'), and I'd like that those two modules could run independently from each other (both depending on 'core'). But I'd also like to have the possibility to run them together, and access frontend when the path is '/' and admin when the path is '/admin', which is the part I'm struggling to achieve.

What I've done so far:
I'm using Gradle. I've created a parent module at root level. This parent module contains the just the main method for Spring Boot to init, and depends on both 'frontend' and 'admin' (both which, in turn, depend on 'core'). I've created a Controller on each of these two modules, and if the path is different they work fine. But still, they work as they belong to the same application, and both are mapped to the same context path. I want to be able to map "/login" on each module and let Spring decide where to execute based on context path ("localhost:8080/login" should be mapped to 'frontend' module Controller, "localhost:8080/admin/login" should be mapped to 'admin' module Controller).

Just to clarify, if the approach I'm using is not the best for what I'm trying to achieve, I'm happy to change it.